# Error MSB3191 Unable to create directory on MSBuild

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I'm getting below error while trying to build the solution
MSB3191 Unable to create directory "obj\Debug\net5.0\Razor\Pages". Could not find a part of the path 'obj\Debug\net5.0\Razor\Pages'

What I have tried so far:

1. Given full permissions to obj folder
2. Closed and reopened the VS
3. Clean & rebuild the solution couple of times.
4. Changing the configuration settings from Debug to Release and vice versa but nothing changed.
5. Running Visual Studio under administration account.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by moving my project from network drive to PC's drive. Now Visual studio automatically creating the required folders.